# A single word for a man who is not exclusively attracted to men

Tags: word-request

In particular, I am looking for a word that encompasses all of heterosexuals, bisexuals and so on, excluding those men who are only into men.

EDIT: Two words are admissible; something like 'XYZ man' is fine by me.

Comment: Why is 'bisexual' not suitable? If a male is not exclusively attracted to other males, then they must also logically be attracted to females. That is what a bisexual person is.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you specifically looking for a word to mean "bisexual **man**" (excluding bisexual women)? We don't even have a word for a *heterosexual* man as distinct from a heterosexual woman.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: *...must also logically be attracted to females?*  Not if they're ***asexual***

Comment: @FumbleFingers - well, I was also thinking about animals, statues, and other things in a list of paraphilias that I saw. In 2013 an Australian woman, Jodi Rose, married the Le Pont du Diable Bridge in France, in 2016 an American man was refused permission to marry his computer, In 2020, a Russian woman, Rain Gordon, married a briefcase.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - but if a man was asexual, wouldn't it be silly to say that they are not _exclusively_ attracted to men? They aren't attracted to anyone.

Comment: Non-homosexual men....

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unlikely to be answerable.

Comment: There is an interesting [list of terms](https://www.stonewall.org.uk/list-lgbtq-terms) on the Stonewall website.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey the word 'bisexual' excludes heterosexuals. Doesn't it only refer to people who are attracted to both men and women, as opposed to heterosexuals, who are only into the opposite?

Comment: "Men who have sex with men" (MSM) is a commonly used term in sexual health etc. So the logical answer would be "men who have sex with women". (Question could be clearer though.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your question is that you assume a single term exists to encompass two different types of sexuality whilst excluding another. But most accepted terms that describe a person's sexual preference are based on inclusion rather than exclusion - for example, *homosexual* means a person is attracted to the same sex as their own, rather than that they are *not attracted* to the opposite sex, even though that is tacitly understood.

In the absence of a single word, the only way I can think to describe the groups to whom you refer would be "*persons with an attraction to the opposite sex*". That definition *includes* heterosexual and bisexual persons, but does not include persons who are exclusively homosexual.

Comment: "Persons with an attraction to the opposite sex" are usually called heterosexuals.

Comment: @Lambie do bisexuals not have an attraction to the opposite sex, as well as to their own?

Comment: Yes, but that would be: bisexuals are attracted to "both sexes".

Comment: @lambie But the OP isn't looking for a definition of bisexuals.

Comment: bisexual=*attracted to both sexes*; heterosexual=*attracted to the opposite sex*. So,  your definition does not work.

Comment: In some cultures there is a third sex , Māhūs, hijras, fa'afafine, and Balkan sworn virgins. I think an attraction to the last would be unlikely to be consummated, but the attraction could be felt by someone.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yeah, but I believe we are in the Western canon here. There are also intersex people.

Comment: @lambie So, would you also say that the definition "persons who like ice-cream" could not apply to people who like other desserts as well?

Comment: @lambie Intersex is not a sexual attraction.

Comment: Never mind. I am merely pointing out the obvious. Persons solely attracted to the opposite sex are traditionally called heterosexual. Period.

Comment: @lambie you added the word 'solely' that time. That changes everything. And the OP is not looking for a definition of persons who are solely attracted to anything. They are looking for something that encompasses *both* heterosexuals (attracted to the opposite sex) **and** bisexuals (attracted to the opposite sex *as well*).

Comment: Oh but there is all sorts. males, females and intersex.

Comment: Yeah, this is a moot discussion about logic vs understandability, which helpfulness (as well as the answer's) can only really be judged by the OP, who didn't give any context.

Comment: @Joachim It was certainly moot, but equally unrelated to my answer as to the question. Lambie was conflating sex and sexuality.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a commonly used word or term that covers the category you're looking at. Terms that I have heard used for this concept include female-attracted man or gynosexual man. Neither of these are common, and will likely require an explanation on your part, so it's probably safer to just use the phrase "men who are attracted to women".

Comment: "Female attracted" and 'gynosexual' could describe a lesbian. That's the opposite of what the OP wants.

Comment: "Female attracted male" and "gynosexual male" would be OK.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you are looking for a word that includes heterosexual men and bisexual men, but not homosexual men or women of any sexual preference. If that's what you mean ... I am not aware of any single term in common use that expresses this idea. You'd have to say, "heterosexual and bisexual men" or some such phrase.

We often get questions on this site asking for one word that means some complex idea. Often the answer is, There is no such word in English. Like people will ask questions like, "What is one word that means a tall man with blonde hair who is riding a bicycle and who has liver disease?" Sorry, but in many cases we just don't have one word that expresses multiple conditions. You have to state all the conditions.